# AccessibilityService ~ AccessibilityNodeInfo when click : keep blinking

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice

I used the point x and y to click the pointer in android.
It can be work, when it can click the point of the x and y automatically, it will keep blinking the point of event click and shows much time of clicked the pointer.

Click ((AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK)) : keep blinking

```
public void clickAtPosition(int x, int y, final AccessibilityNodeInfo node) {

    if (node == null) return;

    if (node.getChildCount() == 0) {
        Rect buttonRect = new Rect();
        node.getBoundsInScreen(buttonRect);
        if (buttonRect.contains(x, y)) {
            if(!node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK)){
                count_click_time++;

            }else if(node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"count_click_time 0 = "+count_click_time,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                count_click_time = 0;
            }


        }else {

        Rect buttonRect = new Rect();
        node.getBoundsInScreen(buttonRect);
        if (buttonRect.contains(x, y)) {

            if(!node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"count_click_time 1  not click = "+count_click_time,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                count_click_time++;

            }else if(node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK)){

                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"count_click_time 1 clicked = "+count_click_time,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                },10000);
                count_click_time = 0;

            }


        }

        for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildCount(); i++) {

                clickAtPosition(x, y, node.getChild(i));

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I struggle to understand what the problem is

Comment: when run the node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK. It will load many Toast.
But I want to display one time, so run node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK , it will stop all action.